# OpenCV - Python - cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'add'

Tags: python, opencv

Boa tarde!
Estou começando com OpenCV e me deparei com esse erro que não consegui solucionar:
Segue código e erro:

```
for bbox in bboxes:
#ERRO AQUI!!====================================================================
    multiTracker.add(createTrackerByName(trackertype), frame, bbox)
#ERRO AQUI!!====================================================================

while cap.isOpened():
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if not ok:
        break

    ok, boxes = multiTracker.legacy.update(frame)

    for i, newbox in enumerate(boxes):
        (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in newbox]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), colors[i], 2, 1)

    cv2.imshow('MultiTracker', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == 27:#Esc
        break
```

Segue o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\Rasatreamento_OpenCV_1.0\Multi_tracking.py", line 66, in <module>
    multiTracker.add(createTrackerByName(trackertype), frame, bbox)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'add'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::legacy::Tracker> for argument 'newTracker'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::legacy::Tracker> for argument 'newTracker'
```

Agradeço se me ajudarem

Att,

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom dia.
A seguinte solução funcionou:

Na variável "tracker", simplesmente acrescente a função .legacy em todos.

```
def createTrackerByName(trackerType):
    if trackerType == tracker_types[0]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[1]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMIL_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[2]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerKCF_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[3]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[4]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[5]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
    elif trackerType == tracker_types[6]:
        tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerCSRT_create()
    else:
        tracker = None
        print('Nome incorreto.')
        print('Os rastradores disponíveis são: ')
        for t in tracker_types:
            print(t)

    return tracker
```